# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ComponentProvider

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm using Spring and decided to add REST services using Jersey.
Here my maven dependencies

```
<!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
         <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
         <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And here my web.xml config

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>namespace</param-name>
        <param-value>mvc</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.c.library.web.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ajax</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I start tomcat I've got an error
[image]

What's the problem? My service looks like this

```
package com.c.library.web.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/helloworld")
public class JerseyRestService {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. But I was missing the jersey-servlet dependency.
The following dependencies in POM solved the issue:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```